# Confused about database select query

Tags: asp.net, database

I am following a session tutorial .The problem is this part.

```
  OleDbCommand fecth =  new OleDbCommand(
     "SELECT * FROM YONETICI  Where  YNAME'" + 
      txtad.Text + "' and YPASS'" + txtpass.Text + "' ", 
     con);
```

At this part I am getting an exception named Incorrect syntax -Missing operator(I have tried to translate)

this is the rest of code

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
         "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+
         Server.MapPath("App_Data\\db.accdb"));
    con.Open();



    OleDbCommand fecth =  new OleDbCommand(
           "SELECT * FROM YONETICI  Where  YNAME'" + 
            txtad.Text + "' and YPASS'" + txtpass.Text + "' ", 
            con);
   OleDbDataReader dr=fecth.ExecuteReader();
    if(dr.Read()){
    Session.Add("value",txtad.Text);
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an equals operator.

```
OleDbCommand fecth =  new OleDbCommand(
                          "SELECT * FROM YONETICI  Where YNAME = '" + 
                            txtad.Text + 
                            "' and YPASS = '" + 
                            txtpass.Text + "' ", 
                          con);
```

Try that.  I added two equals operators to your query.

Comment: Of course his txt.pass.text could have an equals sign in it, which means both your queries, and his, are suffering from some serious vulnerabilities.

Comment: I didn't claim it was a wise query to begin with. =)

Comment: @ryan1234 Posting vulnerable code as an answer doesn't benefit the community or the OP.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev All I did was answer his question. There is another answer that attempts to take care of the vulnerability. Feel free to downvote my answer and upvote his. If you want we can _really_ critique his code (why OleDB? are those good field names? you misspelled 'fetch'), but maybe he is just doing a proof of concept and doesn't need to protect against SQL injections. I think it's sufficient to help him immediately and from all the comments he'll know to go read about SQL injection.

Comment: I know this is not sql injection safe code and you suggest me to write parameterized query But this is enough for me Thank you ryan and Ahmet

Answer (score 2):

exactly,you need to add 2 equal sign but i prefer to write your query in a better way
,this one will replace the @Parameter with the value like code below with

```
fetch.Parameters.addWithValue()
```

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+Server.MapPath("App_Data\\db.accdb"));
con.Open();

OleDbCommand fecth =  new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM YONETICI  Where  YNAME='@txtad' and YPASS='@txtpass'", con);

fecth.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtad",txtad.Text);
fecth.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtpass",txtpass.Text);
OleDbDataReader dr=fecth.ExecuteReader();
if(dr.Read()){
Session.Add("value",txtad.Text);
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Comment: [Are you sure about that?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)

Comment: From the link above: "The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used."